# HighChart Pie only showing after complete page load

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using HighChart to draw a pie chart.Pie chart container is in an ascx control.In the page there are 5 controls other than this.Each ascx sections are loading by ajax async calls.Problem is that graph in first section is showing only after complete page page load.Please provide a solution.

```
    $('#arrhythmiacontainer').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        //plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: 0,
                        plotShadow: false,
                        backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
                    },
                    colors: ['#F5F5F5'],
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },    
                     exporting: {
                     enabled: exportingStatus
                             },  
                             tooltip:{
                              formatter: function() {
                                 return false;
                              }
                            },                  
                    credits: {
                 enabled: false
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {                       
                            size:'100%',                  
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                distance: -70,                                    
                                style: {fontSize: '12px',fontWeight: 'bold'}      
                            }
                        }
                    },
                  legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
                    series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: 'Percentage',
                        data: [['NO DATA AVAILABLE',  100]]
                    }]
                });
```

}

The above graph is in first control and it is binding using ajax call.all the other informations in control1 is loading after first ajax call.but graph is loading only after window stop.

Comment: For everyone to be able to help you better, please provide an example of your code and specify what do you want to achieve with the control in your situation.

Comment: @E.Salazar I have updated the question with the code

Comment: If everything is being bound with successive Ajax calls then you won't be able to control their response order, as they are asynchronous calls.

If the data that you fetch for your Pie Chart is (possibly) larger in size than the rest of the elements in your page, the response will take more time to reach your browser (without adding the time needed to render the Pie Chart once it is gotten).

Can you share your AJAX call code?

Comment: @E.Salazar function GetInfo(reportGuid, callback) {
    $("#divOverlayBasic").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            RGuid: rGuid
        }),
        success: function (results) {
            $("#divOverlayBasic").hide();
            callback(results);
        },
        error: AjaxFailed
    });
};'